# Unzip files recursively in DOS / Linux

Tags: windows, linux, shell, recursion, zip

I have a zipped folder which contains thousands of zipped folders contained in itself and that goes down the hierarchy, I have to unzip each and every file and place it in a single folder.

This task is platform independent either on windows or in linux.

Your help would be highly appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: "[How to ask a smart question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question)"

Comment: I agree. Would be good to see what you have tried. What have you experienced in your attempts to solve this? Have you tried at all?